# Pictures and picture names to doc?

Tags: image, docx

I have a Windows folder full of pictures. I want to copy them all into a MS Office document, but with the picture filename written above each picture. Is there an easyish way to do this?

Thanks!

Comment: You might be able to do this with Word Automation, assuming you have Word installed: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/kw65a0we%28v=vs.80%29.aspx

Answer (score 0):

The `.docx` format is simply a main XML wrapped up in a ZIP format with any ancillary required files such as images. It would be pretty simple to do what you need.

I would start by producing an example document, renaming it to `.zip`, and examining the files within.